# how to render django forms manually?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

am new in Django. Does anybody know how to implement manual?
I have newsletter app:
**newsletter/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import NewsUserForm
from . models import NewsUsers

# Create your views here.

def newsletter_subscribe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewsUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           cd = form.cleaned_data
           instance = form.save(commit=False)
           if NewsUsers.objects.filter(email=instance.email).exists():
               print('your email Already exists in our database')

        else:
            instance.save()
            print('your email has been submitted to our database')
    else:
        form = NewsUserForm()
        context = {'form':form}
        template = "home/base.html"
        return render(request, template, context)
```

**newsletter/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Subscribe models.
class NewsUsers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "NewsUser"
        verbose_name_plural = "NewsUsers"

        def __str__(self):
                return self.email
```

**newslettter/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views  import  newsletter_subscribe


app_name = 'newsletter'
urlpatterns = [
    path('subscribe', newsletter_subscribe, name='subscribe'),
 ]
```

How to render this django forms manually, from third app to home template?
And i have in home app base template with following code:
**home/templates/base.html**

[How to use this form on this template?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woEFg.png)

Comment: What do you mean with *render manually*?

Comment: You make it a `<input type="submit" value="Sign up">`, or you write JavaScript that submits the form when somebody clicks a link.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want to include some template form from newsletter app into home app?

Comment: i need to use this newsletter app models and views into home app. I have on home app created html subscribe form. How to submit this form? I put the html template screenshot. <form class="form" method="post" action="**what to write here**">
should i write here <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">**{{ name.forms }}**

Comment: Have you solved your problem ?